# Setting different query timeout for every query using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, timeout, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. There are three methods, each do almost the same, except different SQL queries, like:

```kotlin
public open fun method1() : String {
    val sql = "select * from func1()"
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new MapSqlParameterSource(), String::class.java)
}

public open fun method2() : String {
    val sql = "select * from func2()"
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new MapSqlParameterSource(), String::class.java)
}

public open fun method3() : String {
    val sql = "select * from func3()"
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new MapSqlParameterSource(), String::class.java)
}
```

I need to set different timeouts for executing queries: first method 10s, second 5s, etc

What is the best way to do this?

I know there is setQueryTimeout thing, but it sets timeout for jdbctemplate and every query will use same timeout.

I have two approaches:

1. create separate jdbctemplate for every method with needed timeout
2. use one jdbctemplate and change timeout in every method

I don't know what to choose.

Maybe there are another options.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you have these requirements? This sounds like something rather exotic to me, so understanding what you'd like to achieve in the end might be some nice context for anyone reading your question and trying to find a good solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is to create a separate JdbcTemplate for each query

For example create method:

```kotlin
private fun createNamedJdbcTemplateWithTimeOut(timeoutSeconds: Int): NamedParameterJdbcTemplate {
    val template = JdbcTemplate(//your datasource//);
    template.queryTimeout = timeoutSeconds;
    return NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(template)
}
```

And now in your repository/service class you can use it like this:

```kotlin
private val jdbcTemplateWithTimeout1: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate = createNamedJdbcTemplateWithTimeOut(1)
private val jdbcTemplateWithTimeout10: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate = createNamedJdbcTemplateWithTimeOut(10)
private val jdbcTemplateWithTimeout30: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate = createNamedJdbcTemplateWithTimeOut(30)
```

You can use it in your methods just as regular JdbcTemplate